# Please reopen this grammar question closed as science

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

The question: ['Blown out' or 'sucked out', why would Data make such an error that's not an error](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144556/blown-out-or-sucked-out-why-would-data-make-such-an-error-thats-not-an-err)

It was closed for asking for a scientific reasoning, but that's not what the question is seeking. In fact, science plays no part in the actual answer at all. Data corrects Riker when Riker made an ostensibly scientifically valid statement. This comes from the early seasons of TNG, where Data was really anal about correcting everyone about everything.  The question was why Data would do that. It's ultimately a grammar question, not a science question, and it's a pretty arcane one to boot (it's not something your average person would know).

Apparently my reopen vote expired without success.

Comment: Simply stating that it's not a terminology question doesn't make it not.

Comment: Related question on Space:SE - [Is the air “sucked out” or “blown out” into space when the hatch opens?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5947/is-the-air-sucked-out-or-blown-out-into-space-when-the-hatch-opens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand by my original close reason, given in this comment.

> You seem to be asking whether the terminology is correct in the real
>   world. Unfortunately, that's off-topic here. It would be on topic on
>   space:SE or possible ELU:SE

Now, if you were to edit the  question so that it focused more why Data feels that it's appropriate to go around correcting his superiors, that would be firmly on-topic (and answerable).

Comment: Point taken. I've edited it to remove the science focus and put it on Data's motives